# Microsoft Access / VBA and Outlook - crashes

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

We are trying to build an Access Application. First, it will update the data entry and then generate an Outlook Application.
It will update the data, but crashes because of Outlook (so thats our thought).

What we have tried:

- Early binding / late binding
- DoEvents
- Debugging to find out at which step it will crash, but in debugging mode it won't crash
- DoCmd.SendObject

Our code:

```
Private Sub cmd_Freigegeben_Click()
 Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim sname As String
    Dim sTo As String
    Dim sSAP As String
    Dim sFRE As String
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim iClick As String

     sTo = Me.txt_EMail.Value
     sSAP = Me.txt_SAP.Value
     sFRE = Me.txt_FreigabeID

  Dim FlName As String
    sFile = Me.txt_Link
    sFile = Replace(sFile, "\\file01\", "W:\")

       FlName = sFile

If FlName = "" Then
    MsgBox "Bitte wähle einen Datensatz aus!", vbOKOnly, "Vorsicht"
    Exit Sub
End If
 iClick = MsgBox( _
         prompt:="Die Änderung dieses Datensatzes mit der SAP-Nummer:  (" & sSAP & ") und mit der Freigabe-ID:  (" & sFRE & ") wird gestartet, möchtest du fortfahren?", _
         Buttons:=vbYesNo, Title:="FREIGEGEBEN")
   If iClick = vbYes Then
     GoTo UPDATE
   ElseIf iClick = vbNo Then
     Exit Sub
   End If

UPDATE:
 Call mod_update.freigegeben_update

    On Error GoTo Fehler
    Set OutApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    strbody = "Hallo," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "ich habe dir folgende Wohnung mit der SAP-Nummer freigegeben: " & sSAP & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "LG :)"

    With OutMail
        .To = sTo
        .Subject = Me.cbo_Freigabeliste.Value & " Freigabe - " & sSAP & " , Freigabe-ID: " & sFRE
        .Body = strbody
        .display
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Call Felder_Leeren


Fehler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 And Err.Number <> 40040 Then MsgBox "OMG! Da ist was falsch! Bitte melden!" & vbCrLf & "Fehler: " & Err.Number, vbCritical, "Computer sagt nein :("
End Sub
```

Maybe someone had this case and knows what to do? (we spent 2 days to find a solution)

Thank you!

Comment: Write log messages to a text file to find out where exactly it crashes.

Comment: What does mod_update.freigegeben_update ?

Comment: Thank you @Andre , now we found out, that it crashes in another step

Comment: Thanks @ThomasG we found out, that the error is in binding a recordset to a listbox causes the crash... But we may have a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you get a standard security issue when dealing with the Outlook object model. To make sure just try to replace the `.Send` method with the `.Display` one. A few options are available:

1. Use up-to-date antivirus software (Outlook will not display a prompt then)
2. Use a low-level code on which Outlook is built on - Extended MAPI. You may consider using any wrappers like `Redemption` that uses Extended MAPI.
3. A product like `ClickYes` or `Outlook security manager` which allows suppressing such warnings or prompts.
4. Deploy a group policy to prevent issues from triggering.

Comment: Thank you for your comment :) I will check it :)